# Open GLES 2.0 draw in texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to load an image into a texture, then draw into the texture.

Am I right in thinking that to display a texture you always need an array of vertices and texture coordinates?  So, to draw a square texture I would need to draw 2 triangles to make a square and attach the texture to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's right. For a square texture, the alternative is to use point sprites with GL_POINTS.